# Is there a way to find an account's current transaction nonce?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, web3js, json-rpc

I need to know my transaction nonce because I am doing fancy stuff with contract addresses (which are the keccak hash of my address + my transaction nonce). Is there a way to find this through the JavaScript console?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your comment is correct: use [web3.eth.getTransactionCount(accountAddress)](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactioncount)

Note that the client (Geth) should be in sync with the blockchain.

---

If you don't have a node and want to trust a service, you can try [Infura with `eth_getTransactionCount`](https://infura.io/docs/#supported-json-rpc-methods).

Comment: What if you manage to set a nonce greater than your transaction count on a previous transaction? How do you get the nonce then?

Comment: @0xcaff I don't understand your question, can you please clarify?  If the client is synced, it will always provide the correct nonce...

Comment: I recommend using `web3.eth.getTransactionCount(accountAddress, 'pending')` to avoid nonce collisions when performing multiple transactions in parallel. (If you don't you may get this confusing error message: "Returned error: known transaction")

Comment: Good point joeytwiddle and maybe what @0xcaff was asking.

Comment: web3.py the function now is 
web3_eth.get_transaction_count(account, block_identifier=web3.eth.default_block)

Answer (score 5):

in geth you can :

```
eth.getTransaction('0x0b95eaccd6273fa35bd9e6102c8a7216ee62274940ff52348c8967c13e1c12de')
{
  blockHash: "0x24b5d26d4fca736ca095e4c85e0e8230c2e0b1056a5050824a4bccf7dd84e1f2",
  blockNumber: 1251275,
  from: "0x2a65aca4d5fc5b5c859090a6c34d164135398226",
  gas: 90000,
  gasPrice: 20000000000,
  hash: "0x0b95eaccd6273fa35bd9e6102c8a7216ee62274940ff52348c8967c13e1c12de",
  input: "0x",
  nonce: 377073,
  to: "0xeadefe2cfa52c759e274d6592a938be0217f5877",
  transactionIndex: 15,
  value: 1011030740000000000
}
```

Comment: What if I don't know my last transaction hash? Can I use the number from `eth.getTransactionCount`?

Comment: I'd say more with eth.getTransactionFromBlock(block hash #) no ?

Comment: But if I don't know the block of my last transaction either, then I have to look through all the blocks, which is not ideal.

Comment: The yellow paper says that the transaction nonce is equal to the number of transactions sent by the address.

Comment: you should reverse the correct answer to the one @eth did ;)

Answer (score 1):

Normally I get transaction count using

```
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(
    wallet_address
);
```

This is not enough when sendind few transactions while the old ones are not mined yet, so some people use `getPendingTransaction` method

When, like me, working with Infura RPC, this last method is NOT available at all, not implemented yet; absurd, but this is.

I discovered googling that we can use `getTransactionCount` in the following way

```
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(
   wallet_address,
   "pending"
);
```

This is actually not documented, but works with local `geth` installation and with Infura.

Using this system I can send a bunch of signed transactions one at time in a short time having them all pending and then mined in some minutes.

Comment: Warning: this function with "Pending" option can stuck your account, the same way mine got stucked. I couldn't deploy and mint. It's recommended using the function without this option. Explanation: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/435#issuecomment-583808056

Answer (score 0):

Ethers it's pretty similar to web3 regarding `getTransactionCount`.

[Reference](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/providers/provider/-%23-Provider-getTransactionCount)

```js
await provider.getTransactionCount('ricmoo.eth');
// 26
```

Using the "pending" switch you can get the number of non mined tx for that address

```js
await provider.getTransactionCount('ricmoo.eth', 'pending');
// 2
```

Beware though: it's quite unreliable.

> The `pending` blockTag is not terribly reliable, and I won’t recommend it. The implementation for Parity and Geth is quite different, where one examines the total transaction pool and one examines the transactions expected to go into the next block (I forget which is which), and many backends simply ignore it and use `latest` internally if `pending` is used.
>
> Basically, unless you are running your own infrastructure which does what you want it to do, I won’t depend on it. :)

https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/435#issuecomment-583808056

Answer (score 0):

Its node js code to get nonce of any account:-

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(<RPC-Provider-Link>)
var account = "0x60E7B364092B1f8D96C5C92Dxxxxxxxxxxxx"

web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account, (err, nonce) => {
    console.log(nonce,err)
})
```

install web3 by `npm i web3`. also change account & RPC-Provider-Link before running codes above.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out your transaction nonce through the help of Bitquery APIs.
Please find the js console implementation for the same below

https://gist.github.com/GkM8te-BitQuery/bdb575749742a0ed03e8d968a20c89c1

You can additionally play around with the graphQL query in our ide to get any additional data points.
https://ide.bitquery.io/TxHash_nonce