# The same node quickly submitted 2 times the same transaction, will be wrong, why？

Tags: ethereumj

the error is:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error processing transaction request: known transaction: b323b93e8b3417aef2f1217c8da281ef5d937f9e1e88245207e44a15fed27b54

I fast twice performed the following methods：
demoContract.pledge(message, weiValue).send();

Answer (score 1):

Each transaction contains a value called nonce, and the network doesn't allow duplicated nonces from the same account. The account's nonce start with 0, increment by 1 with every transaction mined.

It is possible your application has created two transaction with the same nonce, the ethereum client will only accept the first one and reject the second. If you want to send several transactions at the same time make sure they have different nonces.

Comment: how to get the nonce of the transaction and set the nonce of the transaction

Comment: You can get the transaction nonce with eth.getTransactionCount api, see here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2527/is-there-a-way-to-find-an-accounts-current-transaction-nonce.

Comment: In fact, these two transactions have not yet been confirmed just commit, the above error is at this time